# woocommerce creating checkbox with multiple choises

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, woocommerce

i am trying to make checkbox with multiple choises.
This is code i used

```
// Add custom fields for product general option settings (hidding it for variable products)
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'add_custom_settings_fields22', 20 );
function add_custom_settings_fields22() {
    global $post;

    echo '<div class="options_group hide_if_variable"">'; // Hidding in variable products

    woocommerce_wp_multi_checkbox( array(
        'id' => '_season',
        'name' => '_season[]',
        'class' => '',
        'label' => __('Season', 'woocommerce'),
        'options' => array(
            'spring' => __("Spring", "woocommerce"),
            'summer' => __("Summer", "woocommerce"),
            'autumn' => __("Autumn", "woocommerce"),
            'winter' => __("Winter", "woocommerce"),
        )
    ) );

    echo '</div>';
}
```

But on site gives error like

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function woocommerce_wp_multi_checkbox() in /home/wordcamp16870/www/vladi/wp-content/themes/astra-child/functions.php:585 Stack trace: #0 /home/wordcamp16870/www/vladi/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(287): add_custom_settings_fields22('') #1 /home/wordcamp16870/www/vladi/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(311): WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array) #2 /home/wordcamp16870/www/vladi/wp-includes/plugin.php(484): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #3 /home/wordcamp16870/www/vladi/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/admin/meta-boxes/views/html-product-data-general.php(186): do_action('woocommerce_pro...') #4 /home/wordcamp16870/www/vladi/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/admin/meta-boxes/class-wc-meta-box-product-data.php(42): include('/home/wordcamp1...') #5 /home/wordcamp16870/www/vladi/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/admin/meta-boxes/views/html-product-data-panel.php(51): WC_Meta_Box_Product_Data::output_tabs() #6 /home/wordcamp16870/www/vladi/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/inclu in /home/wordcamp16870/www/vladi/wp-content/themes/astra-child/functions.php on line 585
```

is there any chance funciton *woocommerce_wp_multi_checkbox()* to be deprecated and unusable?
Thank you!

Comment: You need to add this code too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50802095/3730754 as this is a custom function I have created.