# How to save multiple select fields in woocommerce variable subscriptions custom field as multi select

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

I am adding custom fields in Woocommerce **Variable Subscriptions** and its working fine for all except for dropdown with ability to select multiple. Here is my code.

```
<?php

// Showing fields for variable subscriptions 
add_action('woocommerce_product_after_variable_attributes', 'show_WC_Product_Variable_Subscription_Variation_Custom_Fields', 10, 3);

// Saving fields for variable subscriptions 
add_action('woocommerce_save_product_variation', 'save_WC_Product_Variable_Subscription_Variation_Custom_Fields', 10, 2);


function show_WC_Product_Variable_Subscription_Variation_Custom_Fields($loop, $variation_data, $variation) {

    echo '<strong>' . __("Mindesk e-Commerce", 'woocommerce') . '</strong>';

    

    // Mindesk User IDS 
    $mindesk_user_ids = get_post_meta($variation->ID, 'mindesk_user_ids', true);

    woocommerce_wp_select(
        array(
            'id' => "mindesk_user_ids{$loop}",
            'name' => "mindesk_user_ids[][{$loop}]",
            'wrapper_class' => 'product_custom_field form-row ',
            'class' => 'mindesk_select2',
            'label' => __('Mindesk User IDs', 'woocommerce'),
            'default' => $mindesk_user_ids,
            'class' => 'mindesk_select2',
            'options' => array(
                'Mon' => 'Monday',
                'Tue' => 'Tuesday',
                'Wed' => 'Wednesday',
                'Thu' => 'Thursday',
                'Fri' => 'Friday',
                'Sat' => 'Saturday',
                'Sun' => 'Sunday'
            ),
            'custom_attributes' => array('multiple' => 'multiple')
        )
    );
}

function save_WC_Product_Variable_Subscription_Variation_Custom_Fields($variation_id, $loop) {
    // Mindesk User IDs    
    $mindesk_user_ids = $_POST['mindesk_user_ids'][$loop];
    update_post_meta($variation_id, 'mindesk_user_ids', esc_attr($mindesk_user_ids));
}
```

As you can see here, I am showing select box and I am able to select multiple fields but when I save this, in my database its value saving as `Array`..

I have tried to replace my `loop` variable name something like `'name' => "mindesk_user_ids[{$loop}][]",` but its not working .. I also want once saved, those values to set as selected.

Can someone guide me what I am doing wrong here?

Any guidance will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: WooCommerce `woocommerce_wp_select()` function *(or even `woocommerce_wp_checkbox()` function)* doesn't handle multiple selections… You could use instead this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50802095/3730754

Comment: ok @LoicTheAztec let me try this .. I will update you here soon .. Thanks a lot

Comment: My question is, I have variable names with `$loop` do i need to use this variable?

Comment: The link you provided is for `Simple Product` but I want to `Variable subscriptions` .. do i need to use `$loop` for this ? As I have done the same for other fields to make it work. Please suggest.

Comment: You can use that on for every kind of products even with variations just as you do with `woocommerce_wp_select()` or `woocommerce_wp_checkbox()` existing functions… My answer function extend `woocommerce_wp_checkbox()` to handle multiple selections.

Comment: Well I mean ` 'name' => "mindesk_user_ids[{$loop}][]"` do i need to use like this or something like this while created a multiple select box ` 'name' => "mindesk_user_ids[{$loop}]"`

Comment: By the way .. the function you mentioned is making checkboxes .. i want select boxes

Comment: ok .. I think this will help me https://stackoverflow.com/a/50159063/6829420 .. i will check it out and update you here .. Thanks

Comment: Oups! yes I forgot that one… Try it then.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec yea surely .. i will try that one .. I will update here if that works .. i have already upvoted .. will surely work .. I believe .. Thanks

Comment: If It don't works, update your question with your code attempt and I will try to make it work.

Comment: surely.. i will.. thannks

Comment: I have used your code provided as reference link for `Simple Subscription` and `Variable Subscription` and its working for select box / dropdown as per my requirements. Thank you so much.